Python BeautifulSoup - how to convert nested elements into indented text
I'm wondering if someone can help me understand how to take a website scrape and convert it to a text file using BeautifulSoup and Python. It's from a message board where people write their own text, as well as sometimes quoting from previous messages.
I can grab the text no problem, but I can't figure out how to handle the quoted text (which are represented by  elements).  I want them to be indented in my text output.  There can be simple blockquotes, but also nested blockquotes.  I don't know how deep the nested blockquotes may go.
Here's an example:

    Title
  

    This is quote 1
  
Some text
    
      This is quote 2
      
        This is quote 3 nested in quote 2
      



    More text
  
The output text I'm looking to create is:
Title
---This is quote 1
Some text
--This is quote 2
----This is quote 3 nested in quote 2
More text
Any ideas on how to program this in Python?  Any help would be much appreciated, thanks!
I've tried using get_text() but it doesn't differentiate between regular text and blockquote text.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

You can achieve this with a recursive function iterating over the element tree, such as in the following:
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<p>
Title
</p>
<blockquote>
This is quote 1
</blockquote>
<p>
Some text
<blockquote>
This is quote 2
<blockquote>
This is quote 3 nested in quote 2
</blockquote>
</blockquote>
</p>
<p>
More text
</p>
""".replace('\n', '')

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

def print_text_with_blockquote_indents(tag, prefix=""):
    # Add '--' prefix if this tag is a blockquote
    if tag.name == 'blockquote':
        prefix = prefix + '--'
    # Print the inner text of this tag only
    print(f"{prefix} {''.join(tag.find_all(string=True, recursive=False))}")
    # Continue recursively if the tag has children
    all_children = tag.find_all(recursive=False)
    if len(all_children) > 0:
        for tag in all_children:
            print_text_with_blockquote_indents(tag, prefix)

print_text_with_blockquote_indents(soup)

The function print_text_with_blockquote_indents iterates over the element tree, printing the inner text of each tag and appending the prefix '--' to the text for that tag and all child tags only if the tag name is 'blockquote'.
Output:
Title
-- This is quote 1
Some text
-- This is quote 2
---- This is quote 3 nested in quote 2
More text

Let me know if you have any questions.
